# How to open facebook page in native iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I want to open facebook native app and direct user to my facebook's page if app is installed on the user's device. Following code doesn't work, it always opens browser.

Page ID 1234 is just for example, I've used my page's read Page ID so I'm passing correct ID in my actual code.

How to fix it?

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fb://profile/1234")!) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "fb://profile/1234")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://facebook.com/pageurl")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Have you added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist file? If not please add them with value "fb"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following needs to be added in info.plist for above code to work.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```